# While loop keeps going even though creteria has been met

Tags: matlab, fibonacci

Hello I need this count to stop once my variable 'fourMil' is <= o but the loop keeps going and IDK why. Some help would be appreciated.

```
% Sum of the Fibonacci pair numbers until 4 million

 clc
    clear

    fibo_list = [];
    for i = (0:31)
        if (i == 0 ||  i == 1 || i == 2)
            fibo_list(end+1) = i + 1;
        else
            fibo_list(end+1) = fibo_list(end) + fibo_list(end-1);
        end
    end

    filtered_list = [];
    fourMil = 4000000;

    while fourMil > 0
        for i = fibo_list     
            if mod(i,2) == 0
                filtered_list(end+1) = i;
                fourMil = fourMil - filtered_list(end);


            end
        end    
    end
    sumation = sum(filtered_list);
    fprintf('the sum of the Fibo numbers is %i\n', sumation)
```

Comment: Your sample code functions fine, are you sure this reproduces your issue?

Comment: The while condition will only be checked **after** the `for i=fibo_list` finishes. Is this your problem?

Comment: I want the while loop to stop once the variable fourMil <= 0, but the variable keeps getting smaller and becomes negative, which is unacceptable for what I want. I believe then that the while loop is waiting for the foor loop to complete. any ideas on how to fix this?. also, this is the statement problem if that helps. 
By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a break statement to break the while loop when a condition is met:

```
while fourMil > 0

    for i = fibo_list 

        if mod(i,2) == 0
            filtered_list(end+1) = i; 

            if (fourMil - filtered_list(end)<0) 
                break; %This will break the loop
            end

            fourMil = fourMil - filtered_list(end)
        end
    end    
end
```